# Field detection in Go HTML template

Tags: go, go-templates

Is it possible to check if a struct field exists from within a Go HTML template?

For example, given the following template:

```
{{if .FieldA}}
    <a>{{.FieldA}}</a>
{{end}
```

and structs defined as:

```
type MyStruct struct{  
    var FieldA string
    var FieldB string
}
// In this struct FieldA is unavailable
type MyStruct2 struct{  
    var FieldB string
}
```

Passing `MyStruct` into the template will work fine. However, passing `MyStruct2` into the template will result in error. While the `if` statement can check for nil values, it throws an error (killing the template executor) when it encounters a field which doesn't exist in the current struct.

Sometimes a particular field is only going to be available in certain structs, so is there a way to check if the field exists prior to attempting to access it?

I've had no luck with the [official documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) and have come to the conclusion that perhaps there is no elegant solution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's not a built-in way to check for the presence of a field, but it is possible to write a template function to do the check:

```
func hasField(v interface{}, name string) bool {
  rv := reflect.ValueOf(v)
  if rv.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
    rv = rv.Elem()
  }
  if rv.Kind() != reflect.Struct {
    return false
  }
  return rv.FieldByName(name).IsValid()
}
```

Use the function in a template like this:

```
{{if hasField . "FieldA"}}<a>{{.FieldA}}</a>{{end}}
```

Create the template with `hasField` in the func map:

```
 t := template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{"hasField": hasField}).Parse(d)
```

<kbd>[playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/N3dSa5SORn)</kbd>

Comment: A very nice solution. Thank you! I was unaware you could actually register your own functions like that.